# SharePoint - Chart Web Part Data from 2 Excel worksheets

Tags: excel, sharepoint, web-parts

I am new to SharePoint and I am now making some pages for my users.

My company is using SharePoint 2010 Enterprise.

I would like to add a chart web part into one of the site pages.

I choose Excel as the source of data, so far I got no problem, however,as the data required by the chart is separated into 2 different worksheets in the same workbook. I can only use one of the worksheets data to act as the source of data.

So, here's the question, how can I input 2 or more worksheets for the "range name"?

Please advice what I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look your answer in this video. http://sharepoint-videos.com/sp10use-the-chart-web-part-to-visualize-data-from-excel-spreadsheet/ I hope it will help.

OR

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365trainingcourse_lab_5_1_topic3.aspx